# Yocto (Dora) QT5 on IMX6 : where is qmake

Tags: qt5, qmake, yocto

I ask because after long searchs, I did not find a clear answer : 
- I need qmake for QT5
- I want it in the sdk generated by yocto
- I don't succed to add it
I try to : add meta-toolchain-qt5 or qttools without success.
Where should I find it ?
(and Yes I have to stay on this old DORA distribution)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution (perhaps its was clear for you :-) )
To add the QT toolchain in your global toolchain, in your image file (eg image_types_yourimage.bbclass), add this `inherit populate_sdk_qt5`

1. Add `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` to your image recipe ([see an example](https://github.com/graugans/meta-udoo/blob/jethro/qt5-layer/recipes-qt/images/udoo-image-qt5.bb)),
2. Generate your image: `bitbake your-image`
3. Generate your specialized SDK: `bitbake your-image -c do_populate_sdk`
4. Find your special SDK at `tmp/deploy/sdk/`

If for any reason you prefer `meta-toolchain-qt5` take into account that it will build the entire qt5 toolchain and `qtwebkit` is huge, takes quite a lot to build and is prone to errors (and will also pull a lot more dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

After setting up your Yocto Environment

```
bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
```

This will generate a SDK use for Qt5 Creator located in `build/tmp/deploy/sdk`

You can find more information about setting up Qt5 Creator here http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device